# Object kkapi is not a member of package

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am trying to import a module from another project and did as following:

[image]

As you can see on the image, the imported library is `/home/developer/...kafka-api`.
I am using the importing library in testing. 
When I compile my spec files with statement `test:compile` and I've got following error:

```
[IJ]sbt:auth_stream> test:compile
[info] Compiling 3 Scala sources to /home/developer/Desktop/microservices/bary/auth-stream/target/scala-2.12/test-classes ...
[error] /home/developer/Desktop/microservices/bary/auth-stream/src/test/scala/io/khinkali/auth/AppSpec.scala:14:20: object kkapi is not a member of package io.khinkali
[error] import io.khinkali.kkapi.consumer.{KkConsumer, KkConsumerConfig, KkConsumerCreator}
[error]                    ^
[error] /home/developer/Desktop/microservices/bary/auth-stream/src/test/scala/io/khinkali/auth/AppSpec.scala:15:20: object kkapi is not a member of package io.khinkali
[error] import io.khinkali.kkapi.producer.{KkProducer, KkProducerCreator, MaxBlockMsConfig}
[error]                    ^
[error] /home/developer/Desktop/microservices/bary/auth-stream/src/test/scala/io/khinkali/auth/AppSpec.scala:24:56: not found: value KkConsumer
[error]   private val consumer: IO[Consumer[String, String]] = KkConsumer.create(createConsumer())
[error]                                                        ^
[error] /home/developer/Desktop/microservices/bary/auth-stream/src/test/scala/io/khinkali/auth/AppSpec.scala:52:5: not found: type KkConsumerCreator
[error]   : KkConsumerCreator
[error]     ^
[error] /home/developer/Desktop/microservices/bary/auth-stream/src/test/scala/io/khinkali/auth/AppSpec.scala:25:56: not found: value KkProducer
[error]   private val producer: IO[Producer[String, String]] = KkProducer.create(createProducer())
[error]                                                        ^
[error] /home/developer/Desktop/microservices/bary/auth-stream/src/test/scala/io/khinkali/auth/AppSpec.scala:46:5: not found: type KkProducerCreator
[error]   : KkProducerCreator
[error]     ^
[error] /home/developer/Desktop/microservices/bary/auth-stream/src/test/scala/io/khinkali/auth/AppSpec.scala:47:5: not found: value KkProducerCreator
[error]   = KkProducerCreator(sys.env.get("KAFKA_SERVER").get,
[error]     ^
[error] /home/developer/Desktop/microservices/bary/auth-stream/src/test/scala/io/khinkali/auth/AppSpec.scala:49:10: not found: value MaxBlockMsConfig
[error]     List(MaxBlockMsConfig(2000)))
[error]          ^
[error] /home/developer/Desktop/microservices/bary/auth-stream/src/test/scala/io/khinkali/auth/AppSpec.scala:53:5: not found: value KkConsumerCreator
[error]   = KkConsumerCreator(sys.env.get("KAFKA_SERVER").get,
[error]     ^
[error] /home/developer/Desktop/microservices/bary/auth-stream/src/test/scala/io/khinkali/auth/AppSpec.scala:57:16: not found: type KkConsumerConfig
[error]     List.empty[KkConsumerConfig])
[error]                ^
[error] 10 errors found
[error] (test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Hint, that the package of both project starts with the name, namely:
**The current project:**
[image: The current project]

**The imported project:**
[image]

As you can see, the name differs only at the end. Could it be the problem?

**What I am trying to approach is, to use a function for kafka-api project.**